# Magnitude and Angle of Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I can't figure out how to get the magnitudes for periodic discrete Fourier transforms.

For example if $x[n] = cos(\frac{\pi}{4}n + \frac{\pi}{2})$, I need to find and plot the magnitude $|X(e^{jw})|$ and the angle. I think I got that $X(e^{jw}) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{j}{2}[2\pi \delta(\omega - \frac{\pi}{4} - 2\pi k) + 2\pi \delta(\omega + \frac{\pi}{4} - 2\pi k)]$ although I'm not sure if this is correct. Then I think I learned that for discrete FTs since they are always periodic with period $2\pi$ you just pay attention to the values between $-\pi$ and $\pi$. So I get for the FT, two impulses of area $j\pi$ at +-$\frac{\pi}{4}$. Then I need to figure out the magnitude and angle of this? I'm stuck on this part and also not sure if I got the FT correct in the first place. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you understand complex numbers?

Comment: Maybe? What about them

Comment: You seem unsure of how to get the magnitude and angle of a complex number, which is what the FT yields.

Comment: The original signal is a complex exponential, but the FT yields a sum of Dirac delta functions as far as I can tell. If the entire thing is the 'b' of a+jb, does the magnitude just  equal itself?

Comment: It's possible that the FT is real-valued, but in general the result is complex. Regardless, a real number is a complex one with an angle of zero. Plus, the sum you give in your question has the term $j/2$, which is a complex number.

Comment: So is the magnitude equal to the FT and the angle 90 degrees since it's all imaginary?

Comment: The magnitude of $a + jb$ is $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and the angle is $\operatorname{atan2}(a/b)$.

Comment: Ya, so if a = 0, then magnitude = b and arctan is undefined so 90 degrees?

Comment: Assuming that your sum is correct, one delta function is real valued and has an angle of zero while the other one has an angle of $90$(deg).

Comment: Oops, I actually meant for j/2 to be outside of the bracket.

Comment: If $a=0$, then yes, the magnitude will be equal to $b$. However, in that case the angle could be either $+\pi/2$ or $-\pi/2$.

Comment: You said that you need the DFT, but the expression in your question is the DTFT (discretet-time FT). These two are different, and you should figure out which one it is that you need. If it is the DFT then you need to know the required DFT length $N$. If it is the DTFT then the exercise doesn't make much sense, because it can only be expressed as a sum of distributions (the Delta function), which has no magnitude (it's only defined by its integral).